# Library use Character LCD in Windows Iot Core

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot, c#

I am starting using windows IoT Core and I want to display data from sensor in Character LCD 16x2.

who can I do that ?

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: I am coding in c#. After I write the question, I found a library "CharacterLCD" that did the trick, but I would like to know if is it possible to do it in C#. I found that is possible also to Wiring the C++ code and use as a reference in a c# project also, but I didn't try this one.